What states/properties of a pair of particles can be entangled?
From my understanding two particles' quantum states being entangled is what leads to the capacity to determine a property when the other entangled element is measured. I'm looking into exactly which properties of subatomic particles can be entangled. Can all properties of the particles be entangled.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The question, as asked, is too broad to properly answer. There probably hundreds of various observables that have been demonstrated to show entanglement. Many are combined in experiments. It’s not really possible to provide a checklist. There is no specific restriction on entangled properties. Is there something more specific you are seeking?

@DrChinese Hi I'm basically trying to understand if there are limitations to what properties of a subatomic particle can be entangled.

Properties are not entangled.  States are entangled.

Take any two particles with state spaces of more than one dimension.  Take any observable for the first particle with (at least) two distinct eigenvalues, corresponding to
eigenvectors U and V.  Let E and F be any linearly independent states for the second particle.  Then UE+DF is entangled in the sense you probably intend.

@WillO Of course properties (= degrees of freedom) can be entangled.

@WillO so there is no restriction in the obersvable you choose to measure (from which you use the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors U n V) ?

Voting to reopen. This is a perfectly clear question.

Welcome Thomas Mulier to Physics SE. I am voting to reopen since I think the comments make it clear there is interesting physics to be explained here. This answer to "What is actually being entangled?" may be helpful.
